# Microsoft edge shows the URL when new tab is opened - extension

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I have made an extension for chrome, which opens a specific website when new tab is opened. However it works fine with chrome, but when the same extension (with changes in manifest to make it compatible with edge) is tested on microsoft edge, then on opening a new tab it loads the website, but also loads the url in the website, which I don't want. I want to website to be loaded, but not the URL, as chrome doesn't load the url. I have done something like :

CHROME:

```js
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(
 function(tab){
  var newTabURL = {url: 'http://www.example.com'};

  if(tab.url === "chrome://newtab/")
  {
   // chrome.tabs.update(newTabURL);
  }

  console.log(tab.url);
 }

);
```

EDGE:

```js
function handleCreated(tab) {
 var newTabURL = {url: 'https://www.example.com'};
 browser.tabs.update(newTabURL);
}

browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(handleCreated);
```

> When a new tab is opened, the url is loaded, but I dont want the url to be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is against Microsoft's Extension policy that any Extension which tries to override a Net Tab Page it wouldn't be approved into Store and you wont be able to publish it.

Coming to your problem, it is not possible as of now to make the Address Bar blank or not to show any url.